# Diff in Diff and FE

Tags: econometrics, stata, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I have repeated cross sectional data from the 2003, 2008 and 2014 waves of women aged 15-49.

Here is the set up: I am using a difference-in-difference specification, where my post variable equals 1 if year = 2014. My treated variable are 5 counties in which the program took place in, so equals one if the sample is from any of the 5 counties. So what I have is the standard DID specification where:

yit = a + b1post + b2treated + b3post*treated + error

Now, I want to identify this same relationship using county fixed effects. However, on STATA, when I conduct the same regression, but instead replace the treated dummy variable, with my county fixed effects, I get a completely different result.

yit = a + Bt + b1post + b2post*treated + error
where Bt is the county fixed effects.

I understand that ideally, these two different specifications will normally give the same results. What can explain the difference in results?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing your Stata output. Do all counties receive treatment at the same time? How many counties comprise your control group? Is your post-treatment variable equal to 1 in all post-treatment periods, for *both* treatment and control groups? It could be a coding issue.

Comment: @ThomasBilach yeah all counties received treatment in 2010. and my control group comprises of 42 counties. and yes, post-treatment variable equal to 1 for both groups if the year was in 2014. not quite sure!

Comment: @ThomasBilach so my standard DID code is reg y post treated post##treated. and for my FE, what i wanted to do was reg i.counties post post##treated. but my coefficient for post##treated is different for both specifications

Comment: Try dropping the main effect for 'post' and include `i.counties`, `i.years`, and the interaction between 'post' and 'treated'. In other words, dummies for all counties and all years. Don't worry about variables being dropped from the estimation. Is the coefficient on the interaction term the same as the standard difference-in-differences specification? You have two groups and a clearly defined pre- and post-period. The coefficients should be similar. Let me know!

Comment: @ThomasBilach thanks for your reply! i've actually done this already but still do not get the same coefficient. not quite sure what to do at the moment. in fact it is very different - it changes from a positive to negative coefficient, and becomes insignificant

Comment: I would share your output. But let’s think about this. How many *un*treated $i$ counties do you have in your sample?